# I have few blogs on WordPress, which I want to upload those blogs into Drupal 9, what are the I have to do so

Tags: drupal, blogs, drupal-modules, drupal-9, drupal-content-types

I have few blogs on WordPress, which I want to upload those blogs into Drupal 9 Blog content, what are the I can do it.I have a sheet with all blogs data, what are the best ways.

Trying  to find a module.

Are there any Contrib modules for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Content import" module [from here](https://www.drupal.org/project/contentimport).

Before importing, you should create your blog post content type with all the fields you need.